# Telnet Not Working in Ruby

Tags: ruby, telnet

I need to Telnet into my associate's server for a project I'm working on:

```
telnet = Net::Telnet::new(
  "Host" => "example_ip",
  "Port" => 80,
  "Timeout"=>90,
  "Waittime" => 1,
  "Output_log"=>"output_log.log",
  "Dump_log"=> "dump_log.log"
)# => #<Net::Telnet:0x007f8142321c00 ...
telnet.cmd('ls')  # => "HTTP/1.1 0 ERROR\n\nERROR 0\n"
```

My output_log looks like:

```
Trying example_ip...
Connected to example_ip.
HTTP/1.1 0 ERROR

ERROR 0
```

I know his server is running and I can connect to it. Why can't I connect from Ruby?

(from the OSX terminal)

```
$ telnet example_ip 80
Trying example_ip...
Connected to c-example_ip...comcast.net.
Escape character is '^]'.
...
$ ls
_~1     .TRA 22       4096
TRASHE~1.    12          0
FSEVEN~1.    12          0
20110221.LOG  0         73
CONFIG  .     0        573
20110223.LOG  0         95
20110224.LOG  0         17
20110225.LOG  0         17
20110315.LOG  0         73
...
```

---

Edit:

I tried setting `Binmode` to `false`, `Telnetmode` to `false`, and some different values for the `Prompt` (but I don't know what the right one would be).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem is you're telnetting to port 80 in your code, which is the HTTPd port. That's why you are getting:

```
HTTP/1.1 0 ERROR
```

The server is expecting you to send a HTTP command, such as `GET /index.html`, but instead you're sending "ls".

You don't say what host OS you are using on your machine's command-line to connect to the server, but, it's possible the telnet command on that machine expects the port command to be separated from the host IP or FQDN using a colon:

```
telnet example_ip:80
```

Failing to use the colon on that type of client causes the connection to occur to the standard telnet port on port 23, which seems to be backed up by your `ls` command working. A HTTPd on port 80 wouldn't know what you meant by `ls`.

You can use the Telnet protocol to connect to a HTTPd, and you can use a telnet client app also. You have to use the right command-set with it though. Try adjusting your code to `telnet.cmd("GET /index.html\r\n")` and see if you get a response back.

---

EDIT:

Use OpenURI to experiment. It's a very simple and convenient way to poke at web servers:

```
require 'open-uri'
doc = open('http://example.com').read
puts doc[0, 100]
```

That will open the connection to port 80 at the host given, following redirects, and returning the document received. It then prints the first 100 characters which look like:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Example Domain</title>

  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta http-
```

You don't say why you "need" to telnet to a web server. They don't support the same commands you can issue via a normal telnet session, and won't give you access to the file system, unless code has been written for those purposes.

Comment: I'm using a Mac. Trying to connect to his ip on a different port (say 23, or leaving the port blank) does not work. Unable to connect to remote host.

Comment: I think you're right that this is the problem. Any idea around it? Because his stuff is hosted on port 80 and I'm not sure he'll able to change it any more.

Comment: Don't try to issue telnet commands to port 80. Use a HTTP client, like OpenURI to experiment. I'll add some sample code.

Comment: It's not a web server though. It's an actual Telnet server on port 80. I can issue commands through telnet (using the command line) that I expected to issue through ruby. If for example I issue 'help', I get `$ help
add <ser#>
admin 
alarm [on|off|monitor|reset|<thresh_hi_mph> <thresh_lo_mph> [<N>]]
aout [mph|m/s]
baud [4800|9600]
cal [<ser#> anem [on|off|<slope> [<offset>]]|vane [on|off|<offset>]|analog [on|off|<slope> [<offset>]]]
...` (sorry about formatting).

Comment: These are remote windspeed monitoring stations. I'm trying to log their data centrally.

Comment: If it's a telnet server, then why do you get a HTTP error: `HTTP/1.1 0 ERROR`?

Comment: Fair point. Is there no way I can tell Ruby to treat it as a telnet server? Why is it that I get totally different behavior whether I access from Ruby or from the OSX command line?

Comment: How would a Ruby client be able to make a HTTPd server behave differently? The server was written to do specific things. It won't change. Test it by starting `gem server` on your machine and connecting to its port via telnet.